# custom Table View Cell layout in storyboard seems invalid

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I custom my table view cell in storyboard to make a label center in cell.

but it seems having no affection.

my storyboard is like this:

[image]

actually it like this:

[image]

I only set label's text in code like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Movie", for: indexPath) as! ArchiveTableViewCell
    cell.showChineseTitle.text = chineseTitleArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

why?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you need to set leading and trailing constraint with same constant . if 5 is the leading value then trailing will be 5 also .

Comment: it is the constraint issue.

Comment: @KKRocks Thanks, but I did so, still have problem... I think maybe ui did use my storyboard layout?

Comment: try sunit's answer .

Comment: check your reuseidentifier .

Comment: i think it is dequeue different cell .

Comment: @KKRocks identifier is correct. I tried sunit's answer, it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome @ZeKai...

Comment: @KKRocks I found my problem's key issue: my layout is invalid because my [Table View] -> [Row Height] is not equal my [Table View Cell] -> [Row Height] in Size Inspector. Let them equal fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove leading and top constraint and set the width and height constraint to center the label in the cell. Set textAlignment property of label to center.

[image]

Comment: great :) please up vote and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: my reputation is under 15, so I can't up vote for you, sorry...and I found my problem's key issue: my layout is invalid because my [Table View] -> [Row Height] is not equal my [Table View Cell] -> [Row Height] in Size Inspector

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
cell.showChineseTitle.textAlignment = .center
```

Becouse you do not set text alignment properly for the `UILable`. But only set position of it in cell.

Comment: Thanks.But actually I just want fix my label's position, not it's text position.i mean what I have done in storyboard seems having no effect in my ui.

Comment: I found my problem's key issue: my layout is invalid because my [Table View] -> [Row Height] is not equal my [Table View Cell] -> [Row Height] in Size Inspector. Let them equal fix the issue.